# Android socket communcation

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, notify

Im building an android application that connects to a server trough a socket. However I can't notify the mainthread from the worker connection thread, since it would lock the mainthread and android does not allow that. Here is the following code I have:

Part of connection controller:

```
public void run(){
    while (true){
        while (isRunning){
            if (serverSocket == null){
                try{
                    serverSocket = new Socket("*", *);
                    out = new PrintWriter(serverSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            serverSocket.getInputStream()));
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (message != ""){
                try{
                        System.out.println(message);
                        out.println(message);
                        message = "";
                        reply = in.readLine();  
                        isRunning = false;                                          
                }
                catch (IOException e)   {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }               
        }
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String path,
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> variables){
    this.reply = "";
    isRunning = true;
    String variablesJSON = JSONValue.toJSONString(variables);
    this.message = path + ":" + variablesJSON;
```

}

Authentication class:

```
public boolean register(String email, String password, String displayName)  {
    String path = "User.register";
    HashMap<String, String> variables = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> user = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
    String hashedPass;
    try{
        hashedPass = sha1(password);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    variables.put("displayname", displayName);
    variables.put("password", hashedPass);
    variables.put("email", email);
    user.put("User", variables); 

    connection.sendMessage(path, user, this);

    final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(context,
            "Please wait..", "Register", true);
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                while (ConnectionController.getInstance().getIsRunning()){
                    sleep(200);
                }
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();

    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
            ConnectionController.getInstance().getReply(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    if (ConnectionController.getInstance().getReply() != "SUCCESS"){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

}

I need to wait for the ProgressDialog to finish, however I can't find a way. I don't think an AsyncTask is the right way todo this since the connection needs to be open all the time. Any hints or ideas?

Comment: read [this doc](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html). You can use runnable inside your thread and handler instance to handle messages on UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask is the right way to handle this. And all that you need to do to the UI, do it in your `onPost` method. Infact if you want to call the async in a activity and update the views from the same activity you can

1. Use a Broadcast receiver
2. Make AsyncTask class a inner class to your activity. That way the class methods can modify the views of that activity.

I use trick 2, to get things working. Once I have them working, I take the `AsyncTask` out, and use BroadcastReceiver's. Just to ease my development and demo time :)